# Parse HTML-Tables to Access Database

Tags: ms-access

I am looking for a solution to import(parse) HTML-Tables directly into my Accessdatabase. When I am using the Do.Cmd- Import HTML Command... I get a whole new Table written into my DB that mirrors the content of the the HTML-Table, I am looking for a direct import solution.

Is there any Option to parse HTML-Tables into an Access-Database like the Import for an Exceltable?

Comment: I'm not clear on this -- if you supply the name of an existing table, doesn't it append the HTML to that table? That's the way DoCmd.TransferText works for all other import formats.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not exactly what you are looking for but Microsoft has a driver you can use for this. I don't see a lot of documentation or examples on it but it appears to be similar to the ODBC text driver.

Go here and scroll do to the part that says "Linking HTML Tables":
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164914%28v=office.10%29.aspx

After you have the link setup, if the table and the data all looks correct you should be able to use most any normal Access method to copy the records including copy/paste and VBA DAO loops (the latter being more code intense).